# XCode - stop unfolding by default

Tags: xcode, fold, unfold

Newbie here:

Is there any setting to tweak so that Xcode doesn't unfold the blocks of code by default?

Whenever I re-open the project or copy - paste a folded code somewhere else (in the same file), Xcode unfolds not only that part of the code, but also other parts of the code too.

And with so much code and so much OCD from my part, I feel that there should be an option like this.

Is there?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This question is off-topic. Please read about what is [on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) here and what questions you should [avoid asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask).